# Is the main() function odr-used?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, one-definition-rule

Is the `main()` function [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use)? E.g in the simple program like this:

```
int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not. Not in your simple program.

> **[basic.def.odr]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#3) A function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated
>   expression is odr-used if it is the unique lookup result or the
>   selected member of a set of overloaded functions ([basic.lookup],
>   [over.match], [over.over]), unless it is a pure virtual function and
>   either its name is not explicitly qualified or the expression forms a
>   pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]).

`main` does not appear in a potentially evaluated expression, as such it is not odr-used. Furthermore, we must consider the following:

> **[basic.start.main]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.main#3) The function main shall not be used within a program.

Whether or not that applies to simply *calling* main, or any use, is maybe debatable, but it certainly limits your options to odr-use `main` in any program.

It's worth keeping in mind when analyzing odr-use that it is *the program* that odr-uses entities (or not uses them). Outside forces (such as the implementation using `main` as the entry point) are not subject to that debate.

Comment: And is there any example of a program where the `main()` *is* odr-used?

Comment: @Constructor - My initial instinct was `auto* pMain = &main;` - But given [basic.start.main]/3 I'm not sure it's valid anymore.

Comment: Thank you. It looks a bit confusing for me (especially in the context of non-local non-inline variables initialization).

Comment: @Constructor - How so? Why is `main` being odr-used or not should affect that?

Comment: I think it may be related to the words "If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized." from **[Dynamic initialization of non-local variables](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#4) [basic.start.dynamic]**.

Comment: @Constructor - I see. And so you ponder the case of `main` being the only function in a TU with a variable subject to dynamic initialization?

Comment: Yes, I mean [such simple code sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/05A1uOgMDok24pIL).

Comment: @Constructor - I think it's worth keeping in mind the first sentence you omitted, that it can happen before the first statement of `main` also. `main` doesn't need to be odr-used.

Comment: But this implies it is implementation-defined that initialization would happen *before or after* `main()`, isn't it?

Comment: @Constructor - Nowhere does it say an implementation is obligated to do the same for *all* TU's. For that static objects in the same TU as main, it can use option (a). And otherwise option (b).

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I mean the case of the *only one* TU with the `main()` function in it.

Comment: @Constructor - In which case that one TU can have its statics initialized by option (a). And there's no need to consider option (b).

Comment: It looks for me like the standard has unclear wording in this place. I mean the process of choosing the option *a* or *b*.

Comment: @Constructor - The standard leaves it up to the implementation and whatever considerations it may have. Honestly, I don't see the problem.

Comment: OK. To summarize up: the order in which digits will be printed in the [such simple program](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UCzKbx5FdndWpPdW) is implementation-defined. Do I understand the standard wording correctly?

Comment: @Constructor - No. For various reasons. First "1", then "2". But honestly, that is way beyond the subject of this question. If you have another question on your mind, the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button is always there.

Comment: OK. Then I'll ask the new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this discussion. [I've asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54167232/3043539) as you suggested.