# The initialization of non-local non-inline variables: does it take place strictly before the `main()` function call?

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

Is the order in which digits will be printed in the following simple program implementation-defined?

```
#include <iostream>


struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo foo;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

Some wordings from the standard (**[Dynamic initialization of non-local variables](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#4) [basic.start.dynamic]/4**):

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of `main` or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.*
>
> ...
>
> *) A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side effects is initialized in this case, even if it is not itself odr-used ([basic.def.odr], [basic.stc.static]).

And [the `main()` function is not odr-used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54166888/3043539).

Comment: Since `main()` doesn't refer to `foo` at all, it is implementation-defined whether `foo` is constructed (and `"1"` printed) at all.

Comment: @Peter Could you confirm your words by the reference to the standard?

Answer (score 2):

The permitted outputs are 1/2, 2, and 2/1.

If initialization of the variable `foo` is *not* deferred, then it is sequenced before the start of `main`, so `1` is printed before `2`.

If the initialization is deferred, then the requirement is that initialization of `foo` must happen before any (other) [odr-use](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use) of `foo`.  It does not say that no initialization must happen if there is no odr-use.  The output 2/1 would definitely be very odd for this example  (and the output 2 the only one used in practice by implementations which defer initialization), but I don't see anything in the standard that strictly rules it out.

I believe the reason for the wording in the standard is that it allows implementations to use one guard for deferring the initialization of all such variables in a translation unit.  If we amend your example like this:

```
…
Foo foo;

struct Bar {
  Bar() { std::cout << "3\n"; }
  void Use() {}
} bar;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    bar.Use();
}
```

With a single guard and deferred initialization, `foo` would be initialized along with `bar`, even though there is no odr-use (besides initialization) of `foo` in the program.  In this case, it is also required for consistency because the example uses [ordered initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#2.1), so the initialization of `foo` must be sequenced before `bar`, so the only permitted outputs are 1/3/2 (no deferred initialization) and 2/1/3 (deferred initialization).  But if we used a different construct to obtain unordered initialization, an implementation might also produce `2/3/1` (again, with no non-initialization odr-use of `foo`).